# Confusion over how to code a for loop including a for all addition in c++

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, sum, constraints

I am developing the optimization of a bus schedule problem in c++ and need to code each of the constraints, however I am struggling to know how to code a particular kind of constraint.

[image: Constraints]

The sets i,j,k and h all range from 1 to I,J,K and H respectively. My confusion lies with how to code the left hand side of the constraint. I am trying to use for loops however I am getting confused as to how to implement the for all i,h part. 
My question is how to code the left hand side of the equation, given that X is a four dimensional array. I so far have two for loops, looping from j,k = 0 to j,k < J,K. How would I include for all i,h
Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: Where's the code you've tried?

Comment: What are the legal values for the X[...]?

Comment: X has four dimensions, each with a maximum value of I, H, J and K. So to access X would be X[some i ][some h][some j][some k]

Comment: Double loop for j and k is fine so far, you'll need to pack this into another double loop for iterating over all i and h, so four nested loops in total.  Initialisation of the sum to 0 is to be done inside the second loop.

Comment: You might want to have a short cut (`return` or `goto`) inside the second loop, after third one finishing, if sum is unequal to 1 (with floating point values: don't directly compare with ==, but instead if difference is smaller than some suitable epsilon!), if values all are unsigned, you might have another shortcut to exit in inner-most loop as soon as sum exceeds 1.

Comment: Yea the goto should speed things up, thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pseudo code that would be

```
for all i
    for all h
        sum = 0
        for all j
           for all k
               sum += X[i,h,j,k]
        if (sum != 1) -> condition not satisfied
```

You basically have for each combination of `i` and `h` a seperate condition that has to be satisfied. For each of those conditions you have to sum over `j` and `k`.